# Ruby Rails 5.1.6 tests fail on unique column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm trying to run out of the box tests but they are failing on a unique column. Anyone else having this issue?

```
rails new MyApp
rails g scaffold Person name:string:uniq note:text
rails db:migrate
```

Edited my fixture to:

```
one:
  name: ONE
  note: MyText

two:
  name: TWO
  note: MyText
```

The people_controller_test.rb has this to load the initial fixture:

```
class PeopleControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @person = people(:one)
  end
```

But it looks like it's loading both as I find this in the database:

```
sqlite> select * from people;
298486374|TWO|MyText|2018-06-06 23:21:29.686780|2018-06-06 23:21:29.686780
980190962|ONE|MyText|2018-06-06 23:21:29.686780|2018-06-06 23:21:29.686780
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error:
PeopleControllerTest#test_should_create_person:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: people.name: INSERT INTO "people" ("name", "note", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
    app/controllers/people_controller.rb:29:in `create'
    test/controllers/people_controller_test.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PeopleControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/people_controller_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:PeopleControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/people_controller_test.rb:18

.

Finished in 0.848814s, 8.2468 runs/s, 8.2468 assertions/s.
7 runs, 7 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Removing the test.sqlite3 file doesn't fix it. (I've seen folks have issues with non-uniq data)

I'm using Rails 5.1.6 with Ruby 2.4.1p111.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

bill

Comment: You're correct, name is the uniq field. It's where it is failing ...   UNIQUE constraint failed: people.name:

Comment: Right, thanks. You're probably accidentally re-using a name without cleaning up the database between tests. I use RSpec so I can't say much more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using autogenerated tests containing the following code:

```
test 'create' do
  assert_difference 'People.count' do
    post people_url, params: { people: { name: people(:one).name }}
  end
end
```

Can you see what's happening? The test rails generates for your create action uses the name attribute for the first people fixture. Change it to something like this:

```
test 'create' do
  assert_difference 'People.count' do
    post people_url, params: { people: { name: 'Matz' }}
  end
end
```

That might do it. Good luck.